# java regex isn't matching when it should

Tags: java, regex

```
Matcher headerMatcher = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\\s]*)[\\s]+(\\d+)")
                               .matcher("jumping around 9");
```

So, the first capturing group should be any string with at least one alphabet character.
The following are examples of that:

- Example one
- A       B       C
- A b c d e ff ee ggg aaa

The second capturing group is just numbers.

- 1
- 22
- 333

So, here's my attempt at capturing those two groups:

```
System.out.println(headerMatcher.group(1));
System.out.println(headerMatcher.group(2));
```

And here's the result:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:485)
    at Main.main(Main.java:51)
Java Result: 1
```

After testing at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html
Here's what I expected:

[image: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html]

Something isn't right and I don't know why.

Comment: The issue I find with the accepted answer from that post is that it doesn't explicitly state why the user needs to call the `Matcher#matches` function. It just says that they have to. I believe that the answer given by @anubhava is more helpful in response to this problem generally.

Comment: Yep, not disputing the answer, just flagging that the questions essentially duplicate each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get `java.lang.IllegalStateException` if you don't call `Matcher#matches` or `Matcher#find` before calling `Matcher#group(int)`

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Accepted answer in 6 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

The error No match found at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(...) is simply stating that the received string does not match the regex in any place.

You want to use:
if(matcher.find())